# How to create buildroot external host package

Tags: buildroot

Is it possible to have a host package in external tree of buildroot (the tree that is specified by BR2_EXTERNAL variable)?  I know that I can implement such package and if there exists any package that depends on it, it will be built.  But what if no board package depends on it?  That could be the case for example when we need to build a simulator for the supported board.  In other words, I need something like Config.in.host in the external directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `BR2_EXTERNAL` directory needs to contain a top-level `Config.in`. From there, you can source a host package's `Config.in.host` just like you do for a target package.

There is no separate `Config.in.host` for the external, though, so it will never appear in the *Host utilities* menu, but always in the *External options* menu.

Comment: Thank you for answer.  For some reason I was sure that external host packages are not built unless some other target package depends on it so I was asking how to fix that.  Now I see that there is no such problem.